# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3"\r'

Tags: python

My csv file (test.csv) content sample below: Note: My test.csv file is about 60MB.

```
"Position","Value"
"2545600","19"
"2545601","19"
"2545602","19"
"2545603","19"
"2545604","20"
"2545605","20"
"2545606","21"
"2545607","22"
"2545608","21"
"2545609","20"
"2545610","21"
"2545611","18"
"2545612","19"
"2545613","21"
"2545614","21"
"2545615","21"
"2545616","21"
"2545617","22"
"2545618","25"
"2545619","25"
```

My python code (test.py) below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

txt = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
out = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
mil = float(sys.argv[3])

out.write('chr\tstart\tend\tfeature\t'+sys.argv[2]+'\n')

for line in txt:
    if 'Position' not in line:
        line = line.strip('",\n')
        line = line.split('","')

        line[1] = str(int(line[1])/mil)

        out.write('gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|\t'+line[0]+'\t'+line[0]+'\t\t'+line[1]+'\n')

txt.close()
out.close()
```

My command line:

```
python test.py test.csv test.igv 5
```

After I run the command I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    line[1] = str(int(line[1])/mil)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3"\r'
```

However if I create a new empty csv file i.e. small.csv and copy/paste only few lines (like the sample above) from my test.csv file. Then it runs that command successfully.

```
python test.py small.csv small.igv 5
```

Input small.csv:

```
"Position","Value"
"2545600","19"
"2545601","19"
"2545602","19"
"2545603","19"
"2545604","20"
"2545605","20"
"2545606","21"
"2545607","22"
"2545608","21"
"2545609","20"
```

Output small.igv:

```
chr start   end feature small.igv
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545600 2545600     3.8
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545601 2545601     3.8
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545602 2545602     3.8
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545603 2545603     3.8
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545604 2545604     4.0
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545605 2545605     4.0
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545606 2545606     4.2
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545607 2545607     4.4
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545608 2545608     4.2
gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|   2545609 2545609     4.0
```

That's all I want. So the problem, why can't I do it on a bigger size csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#) module is much better in this case. Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. The issue of stripping white spaces will not arise, and you can specify the delimiter (not needed here) in the argument of `csv.reader` function.

```
import csv
import sys

out = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
mil = float(sys.argv[3])

out.write('chr\tstart\tend\tfeature\t'+sys.argv[2]+'\n')
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    headers = reader.next()    # Consider headers separately
    for line in reader:
        line[1] = str(int(line[1])/mil)
        out.write('gi|255767013|ref|NC_000964.3|\t'+line[0]+'\t'+line[0]+'\t\t'+line[1]+'\n')
out.close()
```

`python test.py test.csv test.igv 5 && cat test.igv` should show the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
for line in ..... :
     line = line.strip()
```

This will remove the line-endings from the line string.

Better solution: use Python's csv module dealing with such aspects for you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module is more helpful.

For example:

```
import csv
f = open("ex.csv")
for line in csv.reader(f):
    print line
```

and data of

```
"Position","Value"
"2545600","19"
"2545601","19"
"2545602","19"
"2545603","19"
```

gives output of

```
['Position', 'Value']
['2545600', '19']
['2545601', '19']
['2545602', '19']
['2545603', '19']
```

which is much more manageable.

Also the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module does writing csv files as well.